# Check if a string contains a disallowed SQL command in PHP

Tags: php

I'm implementing a system that allows to use MySQL queries to filter results. The "problem" is I need to check if the query contains some MySQL commands in order to avoid their execution (commands like drop, delete, truncate, etc).
At the moment my code looks like:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM thetable";

$notAllowedCommands = array(
    'DELETE',
    'TRUNCATE',
    'DROP',
    'USE'
);
$containsNotAllowedCommands = false;
foreach($notAllowedCommands as $notAllowedCommand){
    $upperCaseQuery = strtoupper($query); 
    if(strpos($upperCaseQuery, $notAllowedCommand) !== false){
        $containsNotAllowedCommands = true;
        break;
    }    
}
```

The thing is, if I add the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS
```

strpos will find 'USE' (the command) in USERS (table name).

The same if I use aliases or a column name (deleted_records, for example).

Any suggestions on how to avoid this?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**
After seeing the suggestions this is the solution that I'm going to implement now:

```
$containsNotAllowedCommands = false;

// Remove unwanted newlines and tabs and replace them with space.
$singleLineQuery = preg_replace("/[\r\n]+/", " ", $query);

// Convert the entire query to upper case (for comparison) and explode
$explodedQuery = explode(' ', strtoupper($singleLineQuery));

// Check if the intersection of both arrays is greater than zero
if(count(array_intersect($notAllowedCommands, $explodedQuery)) > 0){
    $containsNotAllowedCommands = true;
}
```

I hope can be useful for someone else in the future :D

Thanks guys!

Comment: Add spaces between the commands.

Comment: "I need to check if the query contains some MySQL commands" - please elaborate. Is it because you let the user/client send those literal sql commands?

Comment: *I'm implementing a system that allows to use MySQL queries to filter results*.  @VolkerK

Comment: @VolkerK exactly! Of course, there is a group of backend users with privileges to manage these MySQL queries.

Comment: @dan-klasson: That was exactly my first idea: But what happens if the query starts with the disallowed command? For example: "Delete FROM tablename"

Comment: Would it be possible instead of sending the concrete sql statement to _construct_ the queries from more abstract parameters? Something like `$_POST===array('action'=>'SELECT', 'params'=>array('table'=>'thetable', 'fields'=>array('foo','bar') ....`? Would be much easier to reliably check the "moving parts".

Comment: @VolkerK: I like the idea, it's a very nice one. Unfortunately the queries can be really complex, so we decided to implement it in that way.

Comment: And/or would it be possible to utilize MySQL's built-in privilege system? (Those ad-hoc sql checks are inherently hacky/whacky/unreliable/error-prone)

Comment: @VolkerK: I know what you mean. It might be cases where the check fails depending on the query. The thing is this is a small module that belongs to a big application which I don't have access. This module is receiving a MySQL query as input and will return true or false depending on if contains disallowed commands or not.

Comment: If the user should be allowed just to read, why not implementing a whitelist approach instead of blacklist ? i.e: allow only `select` statements and deny everything else.

Answer (score 3):

You can try some thing like -

```
$notAllowedCommands = array(
    'DELETE',
    'TRUNCATE',
    'DROP',
    'USE'
);
$query = "delete * FROM thetable";

if(preg_match('[' . implode(' |', $notAllowedCommands ) . ']i', $query) == true) {
    echo 'true';
}
else
{
    echo 'false';
}
```

`preg_match` will check for those words in the string. The expression would be - `[DELETE |TRUNCATE |DROP |USE]i`, which will check for those words with a trailing space and it would not be case sensitive.

You can try this also -

```
$notAllowedCommands = array(
    'DELETE',
    'TRUNCATE',
    'DROP',
    'USE',
    'delete',
    'drop'
);
$query = "select * FROM users";

$temp= explode(' ', $query);

if(count(array_intersect($notAllowedCommands, $temp)) > 0)
{
    echo "true";
}
else
{
    echo "false";
}
```

Comment: can you please explain how this works? so this answer can be useful for others too

Comment: @Sougata:  If the query is: "SELECT * FROM users" it will say that the query contains disallowed commands

Comment: @TJistooshort Added another method.

Comment: @Sougata: you are my hero! The array_intersect was very clever here. I edited the original question with a merge between your solution and mine. I think it should work now for all cases. Thanks! :D

Comment: @TJistooshort Hope so. Give it a try. But there could be many more considerations. like ` delete `.. :)

Comment: @Sougata  I tried delete from table and the script was able to detect it. Can you please give me an example? Thanks